# PageData value returning null inside partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    var cultureRoute = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString();
    PageData["culture"] = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureRoute);
}
```

And not having any problems retrieving `culture` in my views, including the partial `_Layout` view with this at the top of the page:

```
@{ 
    var culture = @PageData["culture"];
}
```

However, after creating a new partial view, `_Navbar`, the exact same piece of code assigns `culture` to `null` when calling it from insde  `_Layout` with

```
@Html.Partial("_Navbar")
```

Why is that `PageData` variable no longer available?

Answer (score 3):

The `PageData` is part of the `PageContext`. When Razor renders a view it automatically combines it with the `_ViewStart` page and a Layout page. While it does this, it passes `PageContext` around so the same `PageData` is available to all 3 views.

Unfortunately, when it gets to partial views, the `Html.Partial/RenderPartial` both work using `HtmlHelper` which only passes a model (which can be replaced by explicitly providing a second argument) and `ViewData` which is part of `ViewContext`. That's why partial views never see PageData from the view that renders them.

If you want to make the culture available in partial views, you can put it into `ViewData` instead. The only quirk here is that while it's available as a property inside views, layouts and partial pages, in the `_ViewStart` page you have to access it through the `ViewContext` property:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    var cultureRoute = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString();
    ViewContext.ViewData["culture"] = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureRoute);
}
```

Then just use ViewData instead of PageData everywhere else:

```
@{
    var culture = ViewData["culture"];
}
```

This [blog post](http://yingbiao.blogspot.com/2010/12/dive-deep-into-aspnet-mvc-razor-view.html) has some more details on how Razor uses `PageContext` while rendering pages.